# typo3 show submenu without subpages

Tags: typo3, submenu, typoscript

I have a website with some pages, presented in a normal menu. Every page has subpages and shows them in a submenu. Except one page. This page has no subpages and should have a content menu which navigates to different content sections on the page. The thing with the content navigation is done with:

```
temp.contentnav = CONTENT
temp.contentnav {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    pidInList = 7
    orderBy = sorting
    where = colPos=0
    languageField=sys_language_uid

  }
  renderObj = TEXT
  renderObj {
    field = header
    wrap= <li>|</li>

    typolink.parameter.field=pid
    typolink.parameter.dataWrap=|#{field:uid}
    typolink.ATagParams = class="linkSubpage"
    if.isTrue.field=header
  }

  wrap = <ul id="subMenu"> | </ul>
}

page.10.marks.MENU.2a.NO.after.cObject < temp.contentnav
```

but this works only if the page has at least one subpage. The workaround would be to add a subpage and hide the submenulink, but is there a better solution to show the custom submenu without adding subpages?

Comment: I do not understand why you put the contentNav into the MENU object at all. Perhaps a bit more context would be helpful

Comment: because I want it to appear like a submenu. It should have a rollover effect and should be visible if the site is the actual site. I thought the menu behavior is easier to implement, if it is in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use a HMENU item with the levels to generate your submenu.
Your behavior is not the right one in the TYPO3 working style. Use the rights TypoScript objects.

And remove the "`a`" from the "`page.10.marks.MENU.2a.NO`". The correct use is `1,2,3,...`

- http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/CommonProperties/Index.html
- http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/CommonItemStates/Index.html
- http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/Tmenu/Index.html
- http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/Tmenuitem/Index.html